# Convert consecutive duplicate character string to known word

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a string with consecutive duplicate characters to it's 'dictionary' word. For example, 'aaawwesome' should be converted to 'awesome'.

Most answers I've come across have either removed all duplicates (so 'stations' would be converted to 'staion' for example), or have removed all consecutive duplicates using `itertools.groupby()`, however this doesn't account for cases such as 'happy' which would be converted to 'hapy'.

I have also tried using string intersections with `Counter()`, however this disregards the order of the letters so 'botaniser' and 'baritones' would match incorrectly.

In my specific case, I have a few lists of words:

```
list_1 = ["wife", "kid", "hello"]
list_2 = ["husband", "child", "goodbye"]
```

and, given a new word, for example 'hellllo', I want to check if it can be reduced down to any of the words, and if it can, replace it with that word.

Comment: You might want to consider whether an [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) function could help you here.  There are implementations of the popular ones (such as Levenstein) on pypi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the enchant module, you may need to install it using pip

See which letters duplicate, remove the letter from the word until the word is in the English dictionary.

```
import enchant
d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
list_1 = ["wiffe", "kidd", "helllo"]

def dup(x):
    for n,j in enumerate(x):
        y = [g for g,m in enumerate(x) if m==j]
        for h in y:
            if len(y)>1 and not d.check(x) :
                x = x[:h] + x[h+1:]
                return x

list_1 = list(map(dup,list_1))

print(list_1)

>>> ['wife', 'kid', 'hello']
```